# Python dataframe как получить все комбинации по заданным условиям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть таблица, в которой внесены данные D1-D10, соответствующий им уровень, статус и кол-во часов. Нужно соблюдая следущие условия получить все возможные комбинации, при которых общая сумма часов не превысит 10 часов:

- всегда в общую сумму должны входить часы по данным, для которых статус = П
- остальные часы нужно добрать по данным, для которых статус = В до максимума = 10 часов
  и представить все возможные комбинации, при которых общая сумма часов = 10

В результате нужно перечислив все данные, которые составляют эту сумму часов = 10, но отдельными записями сгруппировав отдельно данные с уровнем Б и данные с уровнем У и ПР

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[file_xls](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CgSXNXRjjwN5QrinWte9JPd7ZN0nXvtgQ6FRJu8hfQU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: свой код и пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде - в вопрос.

Comment: к сожалению не знаю совсем как сделать в python dataframe (умею только простые выводы группировки и слияния). только знаю как в xls, но в случае работы с большими данными xls не подойдет